# Serialize data from all the Kendo Grid pages

Tags: c#, jquery, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I am working with .NET web application using Telerik Kendo UI.

In steps..

1. Firstly I am preparing view with Kendo Grid filled with local model list. I gave the user possibility to edit data in the grid via InCell edit mode. My grid has set `dataSource.Batch(true).ServerOperation(false)` so that I am just working with a client templates.

My kendo grid is as follows:

```cs
            @(Html.Kendo().Grid(Model.Recipients)
                .Name("NotificationRecipients")
                .Columns(columns =>
                {
                    columns.Bound(p => p.Id).Hidden(true);
                    columns.Bound(p => p.AmountToPay).Hidden(true).ClientTemplate("#= AmountToPay # <input type='hidden' name='Recipients[#= index(data)#].AmountToPay' value='#= AmountToPay#' />");
                    columns.Bound(p => p.Name).ClientTemplate("#= Name # <input type='hidden' name='Recipients[#= index(data)#].Name' value='#= Name #' />");
                    columns.Bound(p => p.Email).ClientTemplate("#= Email # <input type='hidden' name='Recipients[#= index(data)#].Email' value='#= Email#' />");
                    columns.Bound(p => p.ContractorId).Hidden(true).ClientTemplate("#= ContractorId # <input type='hidden' name='Recipients[#= index(data)#].ContractorId' value='#= ContractorId#' />");
                    columns.Bound(p => p.RecipientId).Hidden(true).ClientTemplate("#= RecipientId # <input type='hidden' name='Recipients[#= index(data)#].RecipientId' value='#= RecipientId#' />");
                    columns.Command(command =>
                    {
                        command.Custom("Preview").Click("NotificationPreview");
                        command.Destroy().Text("Delete");
                    });
                })
                 .Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.InCell))
                 .Sortable()
                 .Pageable()
                 .Filterable()
                 .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
                    .Ajax()
                    .Batch(true)
                    .PageSize(25)
                    .ServerOperation(false)
                    .Model(model =>
                    {
                        model.Id(m => m.Id);                        
                    }
                    )
                )
            )
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.Recipients)
```

2. Secondly I am serializing all the data from form `<form class="notification" enctype="multipart/form-data">` to pass edited on view model to Controller.
   This action I am making as follows:

```js
 var form = $(".notification");
 var formData = form.serializeArray();
 var url = '@Url.Action("Action", "Controller")';

 $.post(url, formData, function (data, status, xhr) {
 });
```

**My problem lies in that, passed `formData` to controller is having just 25 items from grid, not all of them.**

Maybe [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BxHsg.png) will also help to visualise difference between returning values of `form.serializeArray()` and `grid.dataSource.data()`.

*summarizing*

Is there a way to serialize all elements of the Kendo grid? Or maybe get the items from kendo grid this way: `grid.dataSource.data()` and then somehow serialize  them to a form that returns `.serializeArray()` to concatenate the results?

Comment: temporarily, to pass all the elements.. before the ajax request, I set pagesize of grid equal to the number of entries in it and when I receive the response, I reset the pagesize to 25

Answer (score 0):

You can Serialize grid data using the following method as

```
 var grid = $("#NotificationRecipients").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.data(); 
 var griddata = JSON.stringify(grid );

  var jdata = JSON.stringify($(document.frm).serializeArray()); //frm is the form name (for serialize the form elements other than grid)
  $.ajax({
        type: "post",
        datatype: "json",
        contenttype: "application/json",
        url: "/Controller/ActionName",
        data: JSON.stringify({Data: griddata }),
        success: function (result) {
                }
  });
```